# Analytics don't track the event .. why?

Tags: google-analytics

HI, I am using Google Analytics to track an event by click redirection. When anyone clicks on a link on my site, there is a Proxy where this code is there:

```
      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'XXXX']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'XXXX', 'web_click', '', '1']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();
```

and after that the visitor is redirected.

The Problem is, that the event is not visible in Analytics ... why?

Thanks
Nik

Comment: Nik, can you give more details about your configuration?

Comment: Well this is the configuration. I have searc and found this: http://andrewblock.net/2010/11/10/create-a-simple-javascript-re-direct-that-is-trackable-with-google-analytics . It seems that the event could be fired only by Event, click or load etc. Is this so?

Answer (score 3):

That last parameter to _trackEvent must be an integer. Not a String. An Event with a String as the last parameter will be ignored without any warning.

Note that it must be an integer. A floating point number will also be ignore in the same way.

```
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'XXXX']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'XXXX', 'web_click', '', 1]);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```